# Detect input value and modify value if not valid

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, forms, html-input

I think this is a simple question, but yet, I cant find the solution.

I have a form that is being validated by jQuery Validator.  I have an html input type that is url and use jQuery to validate that its a url.  I would like to write a script that will detect if the value of the input starts with either http:// or https:// and if does not start with either of those, then to automatically add http:// to the beginning of the value.  Also, I would like for the script to detect if the form value is null, and if it is null, then not add the http://

```
<input name="Website" type="url" id="Website" >
```

Thank you,
CampSoup1988

Comment: I was trying to work out a script using the .change and .trigger functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this...

http://jsfiddle.net/KMc8x/4/

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $('input#Website').bind('change',function() {
               addhttp();
        });

        $('input#Website').keyup(function() {
               addhttp();
        });    
});

function addhttp () {
    // if user has entered 4 or more characters
    if ($("input#Website").val().length >= 4) {

        // if user's first 4 characters are not http
        if ($("input#Website").val().indexOf("http") == -1) {
            $("input#Website").val('http://' + $("input#Website").val());
        }

    // if user has entered 1-4 characters
    } else if ($("input#Website").val().length > 0 && $("input#Website").val().length < 5) {

        // if user's first 4 characters do not have h
        if ($("input#Website").val().indexOf("h") == -1) {
            $("input#Website").val('http://' + $("input#Website").val());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Excellent!  Thank you @Supercoolville!  That is exactly what I was asking for!